# Parse.com not working anymore, no way to receive support

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

We are using parse.com service to manage the leaderboard of our Android game (Real Drift). It worked for few days (the game was released on July the 4th) but since July 15th Parse server doesn't respond anymore (ITS NOT A TIME OUT ERROR). Or better, it responds but the object is always empty. In the data browser, even if it says that there are more than 1 million of rows, no result is shown.

Is anybody else experiencing the same? I checked the analytics and it doesn't seem that any threshold has been passed (we are using the free account):

- Max 3 reqs/sec (limit 30 req/sec),
- File storage 0%,
- Database storage 1%,
- Data transfer 0%,
- API reqs 200k/day (dont know if there is a limit here),
- Objects count 1 mil (dont know if there is a limit here).

PARSE SUPPORT IS THE WORST SUPPORT I HAVE EVER SEEN IN MY LIFE. THERE IS NO SUPPORT EMAIL, THEIR INTERNAL FORUM HAS BEEN CLOSED (VERY HARD TO RECEIVE A REPLY EVEN TO SIMPLY QUESTION BTW WHEN IT WAS OPEN), THE ONLY WAY IS TO POST A QUESTION HERE ON STACK OVERFLOW, AND THE QUESTION CAN BE MODIFIED BY PARSE PEOPLE AS THEY WANT (FOSCO CHANGED THE TITLE OF THE QUESTION TO QUERY TIMING OUT EVEN IF IT WASN'T THE CASE).
MORE, WHEN IT BECOME CLEAR THAT IT WAS A PARSE PROBLEM, NOBODY REPLIED BACK, THEY JUST CHANGED THE QUESTION TO MAKE IT APPEAR AS MY FAULT (INEFFICIENT QUERY).
TO FOSCO AND ALL PARSE PERSONNEL: PLEASE DONT EDIT THIS QUESTION, OR IM GOING TO POST IT AGAIN AND AGAIN.

Anyway, this is the code:

```
public void LoadOnlineLeaderboard(string countryCode="")
{
    loading=true;

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("GameScore").WhereEqualTo("trackId",persistentData.tracks[indexLead].id).OrderByDescending("score").ThenByDescending("playerName").Limit(10).Skip(startingPoint);
    if (countryCode!="") query=query.WhereEqualTo("countryCode", countryCode);

    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequestLoad(query));
}

IEnumerator WaitForRequestLoad(ParseQuery<ParseObject> query)
{
    var queryTask=query.FindAsync();
    while (!queryTask.IsCompleted) yield return null;

    if (queryTask.IsFaulted)
    {
        foreach(System.Exception e in queryTask.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
             ParseException parseException = (ParseException) e;
             Debug.LogError("lederboard loading Error");
             Debug.LogError("Error message: " + parseException.Message);
             Debug.LogError("Error code: " + parseException.Code);
        }
        leaderboardError.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("lederboard loading OK");
        RenderIEnumerableLeaderboard(queryTask.Result);
    }

    loading=false;
}
```

Comment: post the code for your query, please.

Comment: 99% of the time, this is due to an inefficient query.

Comment: Can't stress enough that if you're going to ask for help about why a query is timing out, you need to actually share the query with us!

Comment: im not sure that the query is timing out cause parse doesn't return the actual error but a generic "OtherCause" error code. Anyway, i added the code.

Comment: Can someone please tell us something? Even if there is no issue on the code. We need to publish an update which is ready since several days. Thanks.

Comment: Fosco can you please tell us if the query is ok? thanks.

Comment: What a shameful service. Our leaderboard is not working since 10 days and nobody doesn't even deem to reply.